# How to launch google-chrome/chromium application shortcut in fullscreen/kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, fullscreen, manpage, kiosk

I'm trying to boot a chrome application shortcut in full screen (kiosk mode).

Launching as an application shortcut is straightforward by appending the command `--app=http://website.com`. But the kiosk/fullscreen mode `--kiosk` or `--start-maximized`
doesn't work.

I've looked up the commands through `man google-chrome`. I doesn't look like the option exists.

Is this option hidden, or are there alternatives? A way of starting chrome in fullscreen by default? I'm guessing that there is a way to fake a key press on F11 after chrome has started. Though this really isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: Have you tried `google-chrome --help`?

Comment: yes, its the same command as 'man google-chrome'

Comment: I guess it's a matter of the version in use because `google-chrome  --start-maximized --app=http://website.com` works for me.

Comment: Many of the options below will work, however, you need to make sure chrome isn't running already!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## How to use Chrome browser in kiosk-mode

Use it like this:

```
google-chrome --kiosk http://example.com
chromium-browser --kiosk http://example.com
```

tested with Ubuntu 12.04, `google-chrome-stable 30.0.1599.66-1` and `chromium-browser 28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04`. But **only** if there is no other instance of the browser running.

So **close** all browser windows and then use it with the option and it should definitely  work as expected.

### Other things I've learned

Checking `--help` or `man google-chrome` didn't help because:

```
Chromium has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are added
and removed at the whim of the developers.   Here,  we  document  rela‐
tively stable flags.
```

So `--kiosk` is an option that is deliberately un-document, because it might disappear at a whim... which it didn't since over 2 years. But, well you have been warned.

Comment: Nice one, works fine on 13.04 (though I am running legacy fullscreen support). I take it my issue was that I already had a chrome instance running. Was hoping there was a kiosk mode that would fall back to an application shortcut when exiting fullscreen. A tall order I suppose.

Comment: Confirmed to work on my installation of Raspbian (Raspberry pi 2) with chromium (Full version string: "Version 22.0.1229.94 Built on Debian 7.0, running on Debian 7.8 (161065)")

Answer (score 9):

Peter Beverloo has comprised a list of command line options at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 8):

In my case only `--kiosk` didn't help that much because I wanted to run in app mode (`--app=URL`) -- which disables some distractions like navbar or bookmarks.

I've found from [Peter Beverloo's link in other answer](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) this `--start-fullscreen` flag. So OP would probably go with something like

#### TLDR

```
$ google-chrome --start-fullscreen --app=http://website.com
```

Comment: Be aware that if your URL contains some special characters you might need to enclose them with paragraphs like `"--app=http://website.com/stuff?param1=a&param2=b"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full solution through using it in production for years.  The options prevent popups that can occur and mess with your application.  I will try to keep this post up to date with any changes.

**Run this command as a non-root user**

```shell
nohup google-chrome --kiosk --no-first-run --suppress-message-center-popups --block-new-web-contents --no-default-browser-check --password-store=basic --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-ssl-errors --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2199 23:59:59 GMT' "http://localhost/pal/index.html" &
```

`http://localhost/pal/index.html` is the URL you want it to open.  I have a webapp in `/var/www/html/pal` that is hosted locally using Apache.

I use the [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) command with an ampersand as it is run from a shell script on boot then exits.  You have to run the shell script from Ubuntu's "Startup Applications" with auto-login enabled.

A complete list of flags can be found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Answer (score 0):

I had problem running chromium in kios app mode too in recent rpios (not that's matter in this case what distro (image from 2023-12-11)). I didn't get window to show when I started `chromium-browser` from autostart script, but if I used F11 (fullscreen on/off) to toggle fullscreen then I get window to show just fine - this gave me a bit to think so I did few experiments...

I could run in `kiosk` mode but `app` mode is more desirable since it disables some annoyance like [Matheus Santana](https://askubuntu.com/users/549252/matheus-santana) mentioned in comment.

### Solution

I found out that if you want to run `chromium-browser` in `--app` mode and `--start-fullscreen` you have to also add `--start-maximized` option to command line too.

Here is command what I use for my kiosk-mode, maybe someone find it useful or inspiring :) :

```bash
chromium-browser --incognito --start-fullscreen --start-maximized --kiosk --noerrdialogs --disable-default-apps --disable-single-click-autofill --disable-translate-new-ux --disable-translate --disable-cache --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1 --reduce-security-for-testing --app=http://<app-url>/
```

My chromium version as per 2024-01-02:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 119.0.6045.171 Built on Debian , running on Debian 12
```