# Help with maximize in Bash script

Tags: bash

In this bash script, I want the last command (the Chrome one) to open a maximized (or better yet, full screen) window.

Is that possible?

```
!/bin/bash 

killall vlc

banshee --pause

clementine --play /mnt/4E46682B4668164D/Users/Fiksdal/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Jonny\ Greenwood/Norwegian\ Wood\ OST/05\ Toki\ No\ Senrei\ O\ Ukete\ Inai\ Mono.mp3

cvlc /mnt/4E46682B4668164D/Users/Fiksdal/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Kural/Kural/Puja\ Cropped.m4a &

sh /home/fiksdal/Google\ Drive/Scripts/foo.sh

/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=kefmolhnnppgijjgjcfhlpngbggjlkgf
```

Comment: The closest thing might be kiosk mode. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358898/how-to-launch-google-chrome-chromium-application-shortcut-in-fullscreen-kiosk-mo).

Comment: Look at this http://superuser.com/questions/276923/how-to-start-google-chrome-with-maximized-window, maybe `--start-maximized` will be working for You, I've tried it in Xfce but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Couldn't get kiosk mode to work at all. `--start maximized` works for the main Chrome window, but not for Chrome apps, which is the case here. It's actully an ARC APK build. I found another solution, will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `xdotool` and used `xdotool key [systemwide keyboard shortcut to full screen]` It worked well.

Edit: I found that it also worked to install `wmctrl` and use `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz`